# Quarkus throws `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException` when I use 3rd party library that calls Camunda

Tags: spring, quarkus, camunda

I'm migrating from Spring boot to Quarkus and I migrate one of my services (that worked properly until I migrated it to Quarkus). My current service application don't interact with Camunda directly. It calls 3rd party library (3rd party library use Spring boot) that calls Camunda services.
But I have this exception when I try to run or `mvn clean install` my project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.1.Final:build (default) on project projectName: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: Bean class org.camunda.bpm.engine.cdi.BusinessProcess declares multiple scope type annotations: javax.enterprise.context.Dependent, javax.inject.Singleton
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.multipleScopesFound(Beans.java:288)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans$ClassBeanFactory.create(Beans.java:1050)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.createClassBean(Beans.java:46)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.findBeans(BeanDeployment.java:1009)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.registerBeans(BeanDeployment.java:238)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.registerBeans(BeanProcessor.java:120)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.registerBeans(ArcProcessor.java:405)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:882)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

It is written on the Internet that it is necessary to change the scope of the class itself, but the class that throws an exception is a native class of camunda.
What could have caused such a problem? Because on a spring project, the same code worked without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved it, removing `quarkus-spring-*` corrleation dependency. You can try it.